# setInterval then update page title depending on the outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to retrieve notifications automatically

```
setInterval(function(){
$('.user_drop_down_num_notifications').load('some url');
$('.num_messages').load('some url');
$('.num_notifications').load('some url');
},3000);
```

But what I would like to do is if there is any NEW number retrieved from the .load() function to update the title with a (1) or whatever number of notifications is retrieved.

Like Facebook - when you get a new notification and Twitter when there is a new story to read.

Comment: What's being sent back as part of the load request in `$('.num_messages')` ?

Comment: All it is, is <span class = "num_messages"></span> and then the jquery will add a number to it.

Comment: Ok, and what's in `.num_notifications` ? Are you sending back ALL the notifications ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) comes with a callback which you can use to check the response of your ajax call.  Setting the document's title can then be done with the attr function.

```
$('.num_messages').load('some url', 
    function(dataReturned) { 
         if (dataReturned !== "")
            $(document).attr("title", "(" + dataReturned + ")");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what's returned from .load, but assuming it's just a simple number, try something like this:

```
var num = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('some url', function(data) {
        if (data != num) {
            num = data;
            document.title = "Your Site Title (" + num + ")";
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

You'll still want to take care of the case where the `num` is 0 and where they open a message while browsing the page.

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I switched it to $.get which should stand given my assumptions about the problem.

Comment: That will work, but it won't actually load the results into the div like op had originally.  It could be right though, op will have to clarify.  I'll +1 you when I get some new votes in 3.5 hours :)

Comment: Your answer maintains the old functionality with the new - probably what the OP intended. Will leave it to the winds now!